# Javascript setInterval time not working

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out why the `farmerTime` is not updating when you level up. There is a button that just adds a level to `farmingLevel`.

```
    window.setInterval(function() {
            farmerTime = 2500;
            farmerLevel = 3;

            x = farmerTime;
            y = farmerLevel;
            z = x / y;
            farmerTime = z;

            if (farmers >= 1) {
                    a = farmers;
                    b = potatoes;
                    c = a * 1;
                    d = b + c;
                    potatoes = d;
            }
    }, farmerTime);`
```

Comment: Define `framerTime` before `setInterval `. If you want to change the interval time dynamically, first you have to `clearInterval` then re initiate it.

Comment: Once an interval is set, it will tick at that rate until you clear it. If you want to change the interval, you need to `clearInterval` the current one (hope you saved a reference to it!) and `setInterval` with the new time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `farmerTime` before you use it. In your case, before the `setInterval` function. Also, if you want to change the `farmerLevel` you need to change it somewhere else, not in the `setinterval` function.

Changing level example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="setFarmerLevel(farmerLevel + 1);">Change level </button>
```

And the code for the interval thing:

```
var farmerTime  = 2500;
var farmerLevel = 1;

var setFarmerLevel = function (level) {
    farmerLevel = !level ? 1 : level;
    farmerTime  = farmerTime / farmerLevel;
    clearInterval(farmerInterval);
    farmerInterval = window.setInterval(run, farmerTime);
};

var run = function () {
    if (farmers >= 1) {
        a = farmers;
        b = potatoes;
        c = a * 1;
        d = b + c;
        potatoes = d;
    }
};

var farmerInterval = window.setInterval(run, farmerTime);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot setInterval's function time cannot be change in runtime, so the code is updated now.